# RESET test and AIC

Tags: aic, misspecification

What is the difference between Ramsey regression equation specification error test (RESET) test and Akaike information criteria (AIC)?

From wiki, it says RESET "test whether non-linear combinations of the fitted values help explain the response variable" whilst AIC "tells nothing about the absolute quality of a model, only the quality relative to other models. Thus, if all the candidate models fit poorly, AIC will not give any warning of that."

Can i say that if i want to find which model fits best, just run AIC and if i want to further look into whether there is any mis-specified in the model, i then run RESET test?

Comment: Your logic is fine, go ahead.